# Half-cell reactions and sum reaction below horizontal rule with chemmacros?

Tags: rules, chemmacros, chemformula

I would like to write two half-cell equations (reduction and oxidation) each on their own row, each with their own `label` of type `reactions` and entry *with* `RxnDesc` (reaction description) in the List of Reactions (provided by `chemmacros` reactions module,
*followed* by a summation line (just a horizontal rule) and the sum reaction, which should also have its own label and entry in `listofreactions`.

I can achieve the desired "look" with `aligned`, but that does not give me any entries in the list of reactions **nor labels of `reaction` type**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\ch{1/2 O2\aq{} + H2O + 2 e-          &<=> 2 OH-} \\
\ch{Zn^{2+}\aq{} + 2 OH-              &-> ZnO\sld{} + H2O}\\
\midrule
\ch{Zn^{2+}\aq{} + 1/2 O2\aq{} + 2 e- &-> ZnO\sld{}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: half-cell and sum reaction with equation environment]

I have been trying to achieve that look (except every reaction should have its own label) with the `reactions` environment, but consistently failed. The best I can achieve is a nicely aligned reaction block, with entries with descriptions in list of reactions and labels, but **missing the horizontal rule**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[minimal=true, modules={reactions}]{chemmacros}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\listofreactions

\begin{reactions}
1/2 O2\aq{} + H2O + 2 e- &<=> 2 OH- \AddRxnDesc{Oxygen~reduction~in~water} \\
Zn^{2+}\aq{} + 2 OH- &-> ZnO\sld{} + H2O \AddRxnDesc{Zinc~hydroxide~to~oxide} \\
Zn^{2+}\aq{} + 1/2 O2\aq{} + 2 e- &-> ZnO\sld{} \AddRxnDesc{Zinc~deposition}
\end{reactions}
```

[image: half-cell and sum reaction with reactions environment]

I have tried `\NewChemReaction{rxntab}[1]{tabular}` as [suggested in a previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357511/tabular-with-chemmacros-reactions-module), but I could not get `\hline` or `midrule` to work, neither reaction labels or reaction descriptions, and in addition it doesn't look very nice, visually.

I also tried to use a regular `align` environment and [reset the label numbering as suggested in a previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360919/box-around-reaction-chemmacros) but that answer shows how to do it for a single equation and I guess my copy-paste skills were not enough to achieve the same for multiple numbered equations ;-)

Would love to learn how to do it, if there is a way.

TeXLive 2023, chemmacros v6.2a, chemformula v4.17 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Other related questios & answers:

- [Horizontal Line Separating Steps in Aligned Equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23014/horizontal-line-separating-steps-in-aligned-equation)
- [How can you draw a horizontal line inside an align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254261/how-can-you-draw-a-horizontal-line-inside-an-align-environment)
- [Chemmacros: Redox reaction within align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584779/chemmacros-redox-reaction-within-align-environment)

Comment: I have done this halfreactions/total reaction scheme a while ago. Have to check whether my solution meets your requirements though before I post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be a bit of playing with positioning, but this is the best result I obtained. So I will share it with you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[minimal=true, modules={reactions}]{chemmacros}

\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{format={\sffamily}}
\chemsetup[reactions]{before-tag = \textbf, tag-open = \textbf{[} , tag-close = \textbf{]}}

%----- defining subreactions in reaction ----
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subreactions}{%
    \refstepcounter{reaction}%
    \protected@edef\theparentequation{\thereaction}%
    \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{reaction}}%
    \setcounter{reaction}{0}%
    \def\thereaction{\theparentequation\alph{reaction}}%
    \ignorespaces
    }{%
    \setcounter{reaction}{\value{parentequation}}%
    \ignorespacesafterend
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\listofreactions

    \raisebox{-39pt}{\hspace{20mm} \rule{70mm}{1pt}}
    \vspace{-51pt}
\begin{subreactions}
    \begin{reactions}
    1/2 O2 + H2O + 2 \el &<=> 2 OH\mch[] \AddRxnDesc{Oxygen~reduction~in~water} \\
    Zn\pch[2] + 2 OH\mch[] &-> ZnO + H2O \AddRxnDesc{Zinc~hydroxide~to~oxide}
\end{reactions}
\end{subreactions}
\vspace{-12pt}
    \addtocounter{reaction}{-1}
    \begin{reaction}
        Zn\pch[2]\aq{} + 1/2 O2\aq{} -> ZnO\sld{} \quad \quad \quad \AddRxnDesc{Zinc~deposition}
    \end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image: subreactions adjusted]

*Notes:*

1. As you can see, placing the total reaction outside the `subreactions/reactions` environment doesn't align the reaction arrow with the previous ones automatically. You can adjust the arrow position of the total reaction by adding `\quad` a few times before the `\AddRxnDesc`.
2. I altered your reactions to the conventional presentation. Inside a half reaction phases aren't used as there are electrons involved. Those don't have a phase, only an origin. Conventionally, when using phases inside a reaction, all compounds should be assigned their phase. Phases can be added to the total reaction.
3. I changed the way you added charges to ions using the `chemmacros` definitions.
4. The `array` environment used by `reactions` prohibits the use of lines inside that environment. It looks like a table but it doesn't behave like one. So you need to place the rule before the `subreactions` start and play with the vertical and horizontal spacing of these two.
5. To get the correct reaction number, you'll need to adjust the `\thereaction` counter before adding the total reaction.
6. The `subreactions` macro isn't my idea. I copied it a few year back from an answer to a similar question give by Clemens Niederberger. I didn't find it for now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! And thanks for the helpful notes :-)
Here's hoping for a future half-cell/sum reaction environment (perhaps in `chemmacros`?) that handles the horizontal and vertical alignments automatically for the user. I do like that the half-cell reactions get labelled as "sub"-reactions, neat touch!

Comment: And you're right, this kind of code has been shared before on TeX.SE.
I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603667/10824) by leandriis (2021-07-04), who cites [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356406/134144) by Craig (2017-03-01).